# modernizr In react with styles components

Tags: reactjs, modernizr

I am using nextjs for a site and have my css in
Styles components. I want to import modernizr and use this to detect browser features and change the css in my styles components accordingly. I can see I could just use a script tag in the html file but wanted to see if any way modernizr can be used as import.  What’s the best way to use modernizr in react?